# How are web services different to any script on the server side?

Tags: ajax, rest, web-services

If I make a basic web-based user management application which:

- Is operation based - to make a new user the 'create_user' operation is invoked with all the significant data to create that user as arguments
- Uses AJAX to complete operations without the user leaving the page (meaning that it only uses HTTP GET and POST)

Does this count as a web service and if not why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially a web service (as opposed to an application or GUI) is usually something where you exchange data in a machine-readable format such as JSON or XML. This means that the service can be accessed either by a human or another computer program. Normally in the human case you'd actually have a GUI for the human to use, and the GUI (web app, mobile app, desktop app, whatever) uses the web service to send and receive data from the backend (e.g. database). But also some other automated program could call it as well and get the same info.

With what used to be thought of as a traditional web app, where the GUI and the data access and business logic are all wrapped up in the same application, with only the GUI pages as endpoints, the access by another computer program is difficult or even impossible.

That to me, is the essential thing that defines a web service. In your example, the operation-based endpoint that you mentioned would be the service, and the web page which uses AJAX to call it would be a client which uses that service, but need not necessarily be the only client.

And there's nothing about a web service which requires the use of AJAX etc - that's purely a detail of the client implementation. The important thing is that the service accepts HTTP requests and returns responses, including error codes etc if required, in a structured form that another computer program can parse and make use of.